# combine a button to image

Tags: android, image, button, combinations

i'm new in here and this is my first question
what i want to do is to add a button on the image and make it stick to image
i mean when i'm scaling the image i want the button to be scaled with the image.
simply put i want a button that sticks to it's position in the image, 
for example I a have an image and a button that should be in a specific point on the image,
i design it in eclipse but with scaling the image, button is still in the previos position.

i hope that u understand what  i am saying!!!!!

thank you..

and here is the code that i'm using for scaling the image.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

   private ImageView img;
   private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   private float scale = 1f;
   private ScaleGestureDetector SGD;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      SGD = new ScaleGestureDetector(this,new ScaleListener());
      img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
      Button b =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      SGD.onTouchEvent(ev);
      return true;
   }

   private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.
   SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
   @Override
   public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
      scale *= detector.getScaleFactor();
      scale = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scale, 5.0f));
      matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
      img.setImageMatrix(matrix);


      return true;
   }
}

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: is it the same requirement ?

Comment: @SweetWisher ツ hello again my friend..thanks for your helping ....... the previous scaling problem is fixed and now I have to figure out this one....I want to design a button to somewhere in the image that after scaling the image the button should stay in it's original position in scaled image ..... when i simply put a button .. that button sticks to the image view, not the image itself....I hope that u understand me...It's hard to describe...if you didn't understand tell me to record a video .. my yahoo ID is pouyaparak@yahoo.com and facebook page pouya parak..I think chatting will be better.

Comment: @SweetWisherツ hello again my friend..thanks for your helping ....... the previous scaling problem is fixed and now I have to figure out this one....I want to design a button to somewhere in the image that after scaling the image the button should stay in it's original position in scaled image ..... when i simply put a button .. that button sticks to the image view, not the image itself....I hope that u understand me...It's hard to describe...if you didn't understand tell me to record a video ..

Comment: @SweetWisherツ help me please

Comment: yaa say ..I am not getting you.show me the video. and [ask your queries here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13436/smart-developers-lab)

Answer (score 0):

just use a image button, look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Comment: I have tried it ... but still i have the same problem